# How to use Firebase with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've looked at different ruby gems like  [firebase-ruby](https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby/) and [rest-firebase](https://github.com/CodementorIO/rest-firebase/), but the gems don't integrate well with rails.

My question is, is there an easier way of using the ApplicationRecord design pattern with Firebase as my backend?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly you need to get two things

1. **FIREBASE_SERVER_API_KEY**
2. **FIREBASE_NOTIFICATION_URL**.

After that just pass these in headers

```
{"Authorization" => "key=#{FIREBASE_SERVER_API_KEY}", "Content-Type" => "application/json"}
```

And in body pass these

```
{"registration_ids":
["pass-device-token"],
"priority":"high",
"data":{}}
```